# Which program does receive command line commands?

Tags: command-line

When you write on the terminal 'vim filename', i know vim receives filename as a parameter but i guess that a program receives vim as a parameter too... is it just the terminal emulator or another program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the point at which you type `vim filename` on the command line, the shell has already started, so the shell (and the terminal emulator) does not get `vim` as a command line argument.

`vim`, on the other hand does, but this is not available to the user.  When a program is started, its name is *usually* given as the zeroth command line argument.  You can see this by starting a shell and echoing `$0`:

```
$ sh
$ echo $0
sh
$ exit
```

The shell executes the commands on the command line using `execve()` (or a similar `exec()` function), whose [POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/functions/execve.html) says

> The value in `argv[0]` should point to a filename string that is associated with the process being started by one of the `exec` functions.

`argv[0]` in the text above corresponds to `$0` in a shell script.

The Rationale section goes on to say:

> The requirement on a Strictly Conforming POSIX Application also states that **the value passed as the first argument be a filename string associated with the process being started**. Although some existing applications pass a pathname rather than a filename string in some circumstances, a filename string is more generally useful, since the common usage of `argv[0]` is in printing diagnostics. In some cases the filename passed is not the actual filename of the file; for example, many implementations of the login utility use a convention of prefixing a `<hyphen-minus>` (`-`) to the actual filename, which indicates to the command interpreter being invoked that it is a "login shell".

Comment: Might worth mentioning that behind the scenes, shells call `execve()` types of functions, which have parameters for commandz arguments, and environment variables.